# NetworkX trivially nested views

Tags: python, graph, networkx

From the [`networkx.DiGraph.reverse`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.DiGraph.reverse.html) documentation.

> `DiGraph.reverse(copy=True)[source]`
>   Returns the reverse of the graph.
>   The reverse is a graph with the same nodes and edges but with the directions of the edges reversed.
>
> `copy (bool optional (default=True))` – If True, return a new DiGraph holding the reversed edges. If False, the reverse graph is created using a view of the original graph.

From the networkx  [graph views](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/index.html#module-networkx.classes.graphviews) documentation:

> Note: Since graphviews look like graphs, one can end up with view-of-view-of-view chains. Be careful with chains because they become very slow with about 15 nested views.

#### Question

If I am repeatedly calling `G.reverse(copy=False)` on my graph to alternate between the original and reverse views, will this cause a so called "nested chain of views", even though the views are trivially cyclic?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that way:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.directed_configuration_model([1,5]*30, [2,3,4]*20)  #a simple directed graph
H = G.reverse(copy = False)
H
>  <networkx.classes.graphviews.MultiReverseView at 0x10bf61c88>
I = H.reverse(copy = False)
I
>  <networkx.classes.graphviews.MultiReverseView at 0x10bf69a90>
```

If you look at the source code, in the case `copy = False`, it calls `reverse_view`, whose code is [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/_modules/networkx/classes/graphviews.html#reverse_view).  It doesn't do anything to check whether it's already a reverse view.

It would probably introduce problems if it weren't like this.  You might expect a view to behave differently from a graph, and if it actually gave back the graph, code might misbehave.

Comment: I agree that it should always return a view, however the question isn't about whether it should return a view or not, its whether or not it doesn't shortcut these trivially views i.e. if we have a chain of views and there are two reverses in a row, they should be squashed.

Comment: It does not.  I don't know how complicated it would be to change this.